# Crystal Reports - Pulling back field does not have text in field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have several tables linked together in Crystal and can pull back the correct information needed so far.

I am now trying to filter a field and pull back records on how we contact our clients with a contact type of "By telephone", which is easily done by

```
{CONT.Type} = "By telephone"
```

now I want to pull all those records back who have not had a contact "By telepone". I have tried so far

```
<> does not equal

If "By telephone" in {CONT.Type} then 1 
else 0 (and various options within this range) 

NOT LooksLike({CONT.Type},"By telephone")
```

I have a total set up of 254 clients and 189 contacted by telephone, but need a report to be able to show me those who have been contact differently. 
At the moment, all the formulas I have tried have pulled back either the whole lot or just the "By telephone".

I would like to just see the 65 records

Answer (score 1):

Your record-selection formula should be:

```
(Isnull({CONT.Type}) OR {CONT.Type}<>"By telephone")
```

Comment: Undortunetely this brings back all the 254 clients :(